# How can I achieve this responsive design without using a container element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to go for the following layouts with this code. Here is a rough illustration:

[image: Desktop and tablet layout]

I also added a media query for mobile layout which will just stack the elements on top of one another.

[My Code](https://jsfiddle.net/placidvids/bs9oyrx5/3/)

Now, I did not go for a **container element** of the section and I also did not put the text in a separate **paragraph element within the section**, and I know that will resolve the problem.

But is there any way to achieve the desired layouts without modifying the structure of the existing HTML?

When I inspect using Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that there are a number of problems.

1. The right margin collapses with right edge of screen on minimizing screen width by dragging the window.
2. The layouts are not being achieved using the 12-grid measurements and if, for example I make the width to something less than 100% for my desktop media query, it somehow fits but that is awfully wrong to do, I suppose.
3. For the tablet layout, I can't get the third section element to stretch the entire width of the screen although I put it in a separate `<div` element with `<div class = "width">`.

So, is modifying the structure to something like this the only way to go?

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="container col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <section> 
                    <div id="beef" >Beef</div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum...
                    </p>
                </section>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Edit: No CSS framework is being used.

Comment: You should clarify if you're using a CSS framework or not. `container`, `row`, `col-lg-4`, etc. are class names known for being used in [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Please edit your Stack Snippet to include the full [MCVE] that is in your JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you add padding and margin to your section this conflicts with the bootstrap classes (col-x-x) so if you dont want to rewrite your css you need to put the bootstrapclasses on a wrapper div and put them all in the same row like this:

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class= "col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
   
            <section>

                <section class="secheader" id="head1">Chicken</section>

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                reprehenderit
                in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class= "col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">

            <section>

                <section class="secheader" id="head2">Beef</section>

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                reprehenderit
                in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </section>
        </div>
        
        <div class= "col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">

             <section>

                <section class="secheader" id="head3">Sushi</section>

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                reprehenderit
                in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I haven't used bootstrap, do you mean the (col-x-x) format? I have defined that in the CSS file, but I haven't used bootstrap libraries.

Comment: Ah okey sorry thought you used bootstrap, but i have tested this html in your fiddle so it should work as you want it to

Comment: Well, I ran it but still for the tablet layout, the third <section> element does't stretch the entire width of the screen.  Do you know why that could be?

Comment: .col-md-12 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

Add this to your tablet breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

the thing you asked(Is a container element absolutely essential for responsive design?)
yes that's true to make a website responsive we use container
coming to the next part
you want the menu items to look in this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAmDC.png) was right?
so I checked the code which u sent where u wrote in this was

```
<div class="row">
    <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">

        <section class="secheader" id="head1">name</section>
          description
    </section>
</div>
```

similarly for all items
so remember one thing when u want to show some items side by side u should store all these once div so instaide that all will be side by side(sorry my explanation might not be clear)refer this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/
so u can write in this way

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4">
          <h3>iteam 1</h3>
          <p>description</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4">
          <h3>iteam 2</h3>
          <p>description</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4">
          <h3>iteam 3</h3>
          <p>description</p>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

hopefully u got some idea
the above code is for showing 3 items side by side
Thank you